# VSCode Search Always Remains Searching

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

When I search for something in VSCODE it always remains searching and does not show any result. I have attached an example here:

[image]

Comment: update it........ if you are using older version

Comment: Not sure how the javascript tag is relevant.

Comment: @phuzi, maybe a strategy to attract the js community for help. :D. Joke aside, Did you try to update the VSCODE and restart?

Comment: I updated and restarted the VS Code but nothing happened. Always remains searching.